# RSpec test to catch 406 errors if the format of accept header is different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a RSpec test to test for wrong content type passed into the request, because in the controller side I am only supporting JSON.

So currently I have my RSpec written like this:

```
it 'returns a 406 if the request is not for json' do
  request.accept = 'text/html'
  get :show
  expect(response.code).to eq('406')
end
```

and the show method in my controller is like this:

```
 respond_to :json

 def show

    org_id = Organization.find_by_id(params[:id])

    @organization = Organization.includes([:BunchOfTablesBlah).find(params[:id])

    respond_with(@organization)
end
```

But that test fails with this error:

> 1) PopulationManagementController show an organization returns a 406
>   if the request is not for json
>        Failure/Error: get :show
>        ActionController::RoutingError:
>          No route matches {:controller=>"population_management", :action=>"show"}
>        # ./spec/controllers/population_management_controller_spec.rb:184:in
>   `block (3 levels) in '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
No route matches {:controller=>"population_management", :action=>"show"}
```

ActionController#show requires an ID, but you haven't supplied one, thus the routing failure.

Try `get :show, :id => '1'`

Comment: yep... but it was in the test so i fixed with with FactoryGirl to cretae an id and passing it where you put "1" ... worked. thanks.